# PROLOG - Amino Acid (RULE)

Tags: prolog

I would be truly grateful for some help -

I have to create a generic rule that will display the long name of all the small neutral amino acids?

Is that even possible? Do you need more information?

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Are you facing problems with it?

Comment: Yes i am really struggling. I don't know where to begin. Please could you help in any way?

Comment: How about some example input/output so we have some idea where to begin?

Answer (score 2):

SWI-Prolog has some tools available: this snippet captures a fragment from Wikipedia, and dumps the data as ready to use Prolog facts:

```
:- use_module(library(xpath)).
:- use_module(library(sgml)).

:- dynamic protein_table_page/1.

wiki_protein_table_capture :-
    (   protein_table_page(P)
    ->  true
    ;   load_xml('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proteinogenic_amino_acid', [P], []),
        assertz(protein_table_page(P))
    ),

    xpath(P, //table(@class='wikitable sortable'), Table),
    forall(xpath(Table, //tr, Tr), (
        xpath_chk(Tr, th(text), LongName),
        xpath_chk(Tr, td(1,text), Short),
        xpath_chk(Tr, td(2,text), Code),
        format('~q.~n', protein(LongName,Short,Code))
        ; true
    )).
```

after that, consult the fragment:

```
:- [user].
protein('Alanine','A','Ala').
protein('Cysteine','C','Cys').
protein('Aspartic acid','D','Asp').
protein('Glutamic acid','E','Glu').
protein('Phenylalanine','F','Phe').
protein('Glycine','G','Gly').
protein('Histidine','H','His').
protein('Isoleucine','I','Ile').
protein('Lysine','K','Lys').
protein('Leucine','L','Leu').
protein('Methionine','M','Met').
protein('Asparagine','N','Asn').
protein('Pyrrolysine','O','Pyl').
protein('Proline','P','Pro').
protein('Glutamine','Q','Gln').
protein('Arginine','R','Arg').
protein('Serine','S','Ser').
protein('Threonine','T','Thr').
protein('Selenocysteine','U','Sec').
protein('Valine','V','Val').
protein('Tryptophan','W','Trp').
protein('Tyrosine','Y','Tyr').
```

and now:

```
?- protein(LongName, _, 'Val').
LongName = 'Valine'.
```

Answer (score 0):

To get started with Prolog see: http://www.learnprolognow.org/